# How can I wait for 2 promises to complete, to run another?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to run two promises with:

```js
Promise.all([...])
```

But they both have their own `.then`:

```js
Promise.all([promise1().then(...), promise2().then(...)])
```

And I wish to run another `.then` on the Promise.all, while also waiting for both `.then` to return if that makes any sense.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sjao5nhv/) showing what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run

```
function get1() {
  return new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(() => r(),3000))
}

function rejection() {/*Handle rejection*/}

function doAll(...ps) {
    return Promise.all(ps.map(rejection))
}

(async () => {
  var p1 = get1().then(()=>console.log("1"));
  var p2 = get1().then(()=>console.log("2"));
    Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(()=>{
    console.log("3")
  })
})()
```

then the result is the correct

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

```
If you run

function get1() {
  return new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(() => r(),3000))
}

function rejection() {/*Handle rejection*/}

function doAll(...ps) {
    return Promise.all(ps)
}

(async () => {
  var p1 = get1().then(()=>console.log("1"));
  var p2 = get1().then(()=>console.log("2"));
    doAll(p1, p2).then(()=>{
    console.log("3")
  })
})()
```

then you again get the correct

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

As a result, the problem is with the part of `ps.map(rejection)`. Let's see:

```
function get1() {
  return new Promise((r)=>setTimeout(() => r(),3000))
}

function rejection() {/*Handle rejection*/}

function doAll(...ps) {
    console.log(ps);
  console.log(ps.map(rejection));
    return Promise.all(ps.map(rejection));
}

(async () => {
  var p1 = get1().then(()=>console.log("1"));
  var p2 = get1().then(()=>console.log("2"));
    doAll(p1, p2).then(()=>{
    console.log("3")
  })
})()
```

Output

[image]

The array of two elements, both being `undefined` is trivial to evaluate. Because `ps.map(rejection)` is an arrow function that names its parameter rejection and does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to work with async operation in javascript, there are 3 ways that you can use.

1. callback
2. Promise
3. async/await

In order to implement the exact thing that you want, the best and the optimized way is using the async/await method.

you can do it like this :

```
      async function getAllData(){

      const p1 = await promise1;
      const p2 = await promise2;
       
      }
```

now getAllData return Promise, you can use .then() to get the result and .catch() to get errors.

to read more about syntax and other features you can go to this site : [explain about async and await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: `the best and the optimized way is using the async/await method` no it's not. OP wants to execute promises parallelly. await does it in serial.

Comment: combined multiple promises into the one promise

Comment: Seyed, let's suppose that you have p1, p2, p3, ..., pn. If you wait for p1, then wait for p2, then wait for pn, then you have a complexity of O(p1 + p2 + ... + pn). However, if you run them in a parallel manner, then you have a complexity of O(max(p1, p2, ..., pn)). The latter is **much** better. For example, 2 + 8 + 16 + 15 = 41 > 16 = max(2, 8, 16, 15). There can be **huge** differences. I believe @AZ_wanted to point this out in his comment here.